# How to get data through Foreign key?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

**How can i get content form foreign keys (restaurant_id and channel_id)? I mean not FK value but restaurant name for restaurant_id and channel name for channel_id.**

**Tabeles:**

[image]

**Models:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
    private List<Booking> bookings;

    ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "channel")
public class Channel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
    private List<Booking> bookings;

    ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "booking")
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "restaurant_id", unique = true)
    private Long restaurant_id;

    @Column(name = "channel_id", unique = true)
    private Long channel_id;

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Booking [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", count=" + count + ", duration=" + duration + ", start="
                + start + ", phone=" + phone + ", comment=" + comment + ", updated=" + updated + ", created=" + created
                + ", active=" + active + ", restaurant_id=" + restaurant_id + ", channel_id=" + channel_id + "]";
    }

    ...
```

**DAO**

```
@Repository
public class BookingDaoImpl implements BookingDao {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookingDaoImpl.class);

    @Resource(name = "localSessionFactoryBean")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Booking> getBookings() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Booking> bookingList = session.createCriteria(Booking.class).list();
        for (Booking booking : bookingList) {
            logger.info("Booking List::" + booking);
        }
        return bookingList;
    }

    ...
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class BookingServiceImpl implements BookingService {

    @Autowired
    private BookingDao bookingDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Booking> getBookings() {
        return bookingDao.getBookings();
    }

    ...
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private BookingService bookingService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "bookings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String bookings(Model model) {
        List<Booking> bookingList = bookingService.getBookings();
        model.addAttribute("bookings", bookingList);
        return "bookings";
    }

    ...
```

**JSP**

```
<c:forEach items="${bookings}" var="booking">
    <tr>
        <td>${booking}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**toString() result:**

[image]

Comment: Where exactly are you looking to get the information at? JSP? Controller or in an SQL query?

Comment: JSP. Right now i get restaurant_id=1, channel_id=1, but i would like to get restaurant name, or address and channel name. With id i can't do much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="restaurant")
    private List<Booking> bookings;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "channel")
public class Channel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="channel")
    private List<Booking> bookings;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "booking")
public class Booking {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id") 
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id") 
    private Channel channel;

}
```

You can use HQL with  `session.createQuery()`.

This gets all `Booking` eagerly fetching associations. You can use `Criteria` with fetch too.

```
from Booking b left join fetch b.restaurant left join fetch b.channel
```

This gets names, you can process it as `List<Object[]>` or use a transformer to DTO.

```
select booking.name, restaurant.name, channel.name
  from Booking booking left join booking.restaurant restaurant left join booking.channel channel
```

Comment: How should i implement this HQL?

Comment: @user3374117 You are welcome. You can use `list()` too, but without `FetchType.LAZY` in  `@ManyToOne`.